# Retrieving CommandTarget during the Executed phase

Tags: wpf

How can I retrieve the **CommandTarget** in the **Executed** callback of a **RoutedCommand**?
Thanks.

**Edit: adding a verbose sample**

Commands class:

```
static class Commands
{
   public static readonly RoutedCommand MyCommand = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

XAML code

```
<Window.CommandBindings>

<CommandBinding Command="{x:Static BasicWpfCommanding:Commands.MyCommand}"
                        CanExecute="MyCommandCanExecute"
                        Executed="MyCommandExecuted"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
<StackPanel>

        <Button Command="{x:Static BasicWpfCommanding:Commands.MyCommand}" 
                CommandParameter="#FF303030"
                CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=aButton}"
                Name="aButton">A Command</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Commands callbacks

```
private void MyCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  e.CanExecute = true;
}
private void MyCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
  //var target = (Button)sender fires an ecception: in effect "sender" is the main window...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var target = e.Source;
```